# CentOs7 server doesn't read htaccessfile

Tags: .htaccess, centos7

I've reinstalled and configured my Centos7 server.

The .htaccess file always worked fine and I didn't changed anything to it.
But now the server doesn't read the file. 
The /var/www/html/ folder has 777 rights.

Anyone has an idea how to solve this problem? 
Searched for hours but can't find any solution.

Comment: Do you have AllowOverride set to none? That would block the .htaccess file from being used, and I think it's the default on CentOS 7 Apache install.

Comment: Changed to all, fixed it! Thanks